# Remote debugging with GDB

Tags: debugging, gdb

I am using GDB to debug C code. The GDB process is running on a Cisco switch image.

I have the memory address of some variable which is a string, and it has the memory address say **0xFFFFFFF**.

How can I know through which function this string present at that memory address is being assigned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a watchpoint to that address by `watch *(char*)0xFFFFFFF`. (This will actually set a watch only to first byte at that address.) [Details, as usual, are in the GDB manual](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Watchpoints.html).

Things to consider: The string may be a constant that is present from a program startup. In this, only a pointer variable (char*) could be modified to point to that string. In this case you will never see memory at that address modified.